# Android- Importing external libraries with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, import, android-library, maven-central

I am new in Android and AndroidStudio, so I`m if this question seems a little bit idiot.

I want to import this project https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView/wiki but I cannot make this work.

I follow the steps and the .arr was added sucessfully to /build, but I still cant use the classes. 
For some reason there is no .jar of this project in my external libraries folder.

I have to do something else to get the lib into External Libraries folder?

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'de.timroes.android:EnhancedListView:0.2.0@aar'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Android Studio 0.4.3, Android Gradle plugin 0.8.+, and Gradle 1.10. Problems with newly added library imports have been fixed in 0.4.3, and that version of Android Studio requires newer versions of the plugin and Gradle.

Comment: I did it, but it still keep the same way. It is weird because I can use the classes in code, compile and run the project on my device but the list still behave like a ordinary listView. The folder External Libraries must have a .jar associate to this library or not?

Comment: That sounds like a different problem.

Comment: But  should I see any .jar on my libs folder?